# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pandas

```
#read from csv top and bottom
def get_interval(row):

   return df[(df['DEPTH']>=row['top']) & (df['DEPTH']<=row['bottom'])]

#Combine all intervals 
intervals = list(perf.apply(get_interval, axis=1))
 
pd.concat(intervals)

#summ al values in kh column in my data frame 
x =  intervals['kh'].sum()
```

I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-d3a755411e27> in <module>
      1 #Displaying and Summ the kh over the selected interval
      2 
----> 3 x =  intervals['kh'].sum()
      4 
      5 #print('\033[93m' + '\033[4m'+ '\033[1m' + 'Total kh =' + '\033[0m', GHZL_13 )

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I was expecting a sum from one column (kh) in my data frame

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just trying to get the sum of the kh column for the rows that satisfy:

`top <= DEPTH <= bottom` (maybe you've got these the wrong way round? but I will use this).

You can do this in one line using [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter the dataframe on those rows, and the kh column, then use [`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) to get the sum like this:

```
df.loc[(df['DEPTH']>=df['top']) & (df['DEPTH']<=df['bottom']), 'kh'].sum()
```

for example, if df is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEPTH':[10, 15, 13],
                   'top':[5, 7, 10],
                   'bottom':[20, 7, 15],
                   'kh' : [10, 23, 17]})

   DEPTH  top  bottom  kh
0     10    5      20  10
1     15    7       7  23
2     13   10      15  17
```

then the .loc[] filtering of the rows (`df.loc[(df['DEPTH']>=df['top']) & (df['DEPTH']<=df['bottom'])]`) gives:

```
   DEPTH  top  bottom  kh
0     10    5      20  10
2     13   10      15  17
```

You can then specify the kh column, and use .sum() (as described above) to get the sum of the kh column in the filtered df, which is 27 in this case.

Comment: I have a large data frame that contains 6K rows. I have another csv file that contains certain number (as top) and certain number (as bottom) and it could be several intervals (top1-bottom1, top2-bottom2) and with the code I provide, I want to take these sections from my large data frame and put them in another data frame.

Comment: That sounds like a different question,  so you should ask a new question for that, with example inputs and output and what you have tried so far to fix it.